# Creating covariant generic types without violating empty interface rules

Tags: c#, generics, generic-variance

Background: I wanted to "expand" the .NET `Lazy<>` type to support implicit cast between `Lazy<T>` and the underlying `T` object to be able automatically unwrap the containing value. I was able to do so fairly easily:

```
public class ExtendedLazy<T> : Lazy<T>
{
    public ExtendedLazy() : base() {}
    public ExtendedLazy(bool isThreadSafe) : base(isThreadSafe) { }
    public ExtendedLazy(Func<T> valueFactory) : base(valueFactory) { }
    // other constructors

    public static implicit operator T(ExtendedLazy<T> obj)
    {
        return obj.Value;
    }
}
```

I wanted to take it a step further by making `T` covariant so I  could assign an instance of `ExtendedLazy<Derived>` to `ExtendedLazy<Base>`. Since variance modifiers are not allowed in class definitions, I had to resort to an empty interface to achieve this:

```
public interface IExtendedLazy<out T>
{
}
```

And changed my class definition to

`public class ExtendedLazy<T> : Lazy<T>, IExtendedLazy<T>`

This works fine and I was able to make use of this covariant type:

```
ExtendedLazy<DerivedClass> derivedLazy = new ExtendedLazy<DerivedClass>();
IExtendedLazy<BaseClass> baseLazy = derivedLazy;
```

While this compiles and works fine, it goes against [CA1040: Avoid empty interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182128.aspx) which says using empty interfaces as contracts is a bad design and a code smell (and I'm sure most people agree). My question is, given the inability of the CLR to recognize variant generic types in class definitions, what other ways are around this to make it more consistent with acceptable OO practices? I'd imagine I'm not the only person facing this issue so am hoping to get some insight on this.

Comment: CA1040 is a bad rule IMHO. It tells you to use attributes instead of marker interfaces, except such a check is orders of magnitude slower at runtime. In your case, you'll have to add a `T Value { get; }` member to it *anyway*.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: If you cache the results then the difference between marker interfaces and attributes is a wash for most use cases as you are usually using a relatively small number of types compared to the number of invocations. CA1040 is certainly one of the weaker and more questionable recommendations though as many would agree that for small projects markers are less flexible but enough for those instances.

Comment: @Guvante of course, but why force me to use something like `static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, bool>` along with reflection calls, when I can achieve the same thing with the `is` operator in a single expression? And it's *still* faster than cache lookup.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: CA1040 says "if you don't have a method you don't have a true interface you have a marker interface and marker interfaces aren't the best idea". It is honestly more often correct than wrong that marker interfaces aren't the right solution to the problem. There are problems where it is a good solution and I agreed that in those cases CA1040 can be ignored. However most things that want to use a marker interface want to use several marker interfaces and it quickly becomes very difficult to maintain which is why they recommend against it.

Comment: @Guvante yes, I agree it's better to use attributes in most cases. I guess I just don't like rules in the first place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic won't work as well as you think it will.

```
ExtendedLazy<DerivedClass> derivedLazy = new ExtendedLazy<DerivedClass>();
IExtendedLazy<BaseClass> baseLazy = derivedLazy;
BaseClass v = baseLazy;
```

This won't compile as there does not exist a conversion from `IExtendedLazy<BaseClass>` to `BaseClass` as the conversion operator is only defined for `ExtendedLazy<T>`.

This will force you to do something else when using the interface. Adding `T Value { get; }` solves both the issue of CA1040 and gives you access to the underlying value.

BTW the reason that `Lazy<T>` does not provide an `implicit operator T` is because the underlying `Func<T>` could throw which would be confusing since the line that throws may very well not have a function (or property) invocation on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see your point, however, I still think there might be other cases where the interface might not necessarily have to have any members but it's just solely used as a variant type declarer. We're also using Lazy in a very specific unit-test scenario, so there's no concern there. But your point on not having a default implicit operator makes sense.